# Use VBA in Google Docs as it's possible in MS Excel

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We need to work on Google Docs using VBA code, for executing some functions automatically (whats it's possible and very useful on MS Excel). Is it possible to use it on Google Docs?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to use [VBA] on Google Docs?

No, but [Google does support scripting with JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

Here's some specific information about Google Sheets - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets